# Intersection Boolean Modifier doesn't work

Tags: modifiers

I am currently trying to apply Intersection Boolean Modifier on a Superman model with a Plane.

[image]

It works fine for most of the plane positions but at that point on the picture, it cuts all parts and doesn't find any intersection.

I also tried to apply triangulate modifier to plane, solidify modifier to model, removed doubles and recalculated normals but the result still was not satisfying. (I can actually can do it with knife tool but since I am trying to do this operation via python script, knife tool cannot help me I think)

Here is the blend file :
[image]

Comment: The meshes used in the Boolean modifier should both be *manifold* for consistent results. Try adding a Solidify modifier to the plane so that it has at least some depth.

Comment: I should apply solidify modifier to the model right? I did it and just a little part of the intersection became visible (other intersection regions still unchanged)

Comment: To the plane - both meshes have to have some volume as the Boolean works on the intersection of the volumes.

Comment: Have you tried bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project in Python?

Comment: adding volume to mesh works better but there are few extra vertices that are misplaced. (Thanks:) )
Also I don't know how to specify the mouse location and draw the line from the script. (Thank you though :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meshes used in the Boolean modifier should both be *manifold* (fully enclose a volume) for consistent results as the modifier works based on the volume enclosed by the mesh. Adding a Solidify modifier to the plane will give it thickness so that the modifier has some volume to work with.